# Pandas calculating the speed between two rows based on timestamp and coordinates

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas dataframe like:

```
timestamp  latitude  longitude
1652846403129   30   20
1652846415130   31   21
1652846427128   32   22
1652846439128   33   23
```

How could I calculate the "speed" between two rows and have it as a new column?
I would have to calculate the distance based on the coordinates and divide by time taken.

I have a function that calculates distance between two coordinates, but it takes two tuples of form (lat,long) as input.

rolling.apply seemed like an option so that I can work on windows of two, but I can't quite get it to work and it seemed only to work on one series at a time.
Something like creating a new column with shifting doesn't seem to work either since the function for distance that I'm using doesn't support the use of dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) function to get the time:

```
df.loc[:, 'time'] = df['timestamp'].diff()
```

You can also get the distance from the previous row using the [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) function using your function:

```
def get_distance
```

```
df.loc[:, 'distance'] = df[['latitude', 'longitude']].apply(lambda x: get_distance((x['latitude'], x['longitude']), (x['latitude'].shift(1), x['longitude'].shift(1)))
```

Comment: I get an error when I try to run this - "KeyError: 'latitude" which I suspect is because the .apply just runs on a single column at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Below code can help in getting the required results:

```html
# Import required packages
import pandas as pd
from haversine import haversine

# Dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':[1652846403129,1652846415130, 1652846427128, 1652846439128],
              'latitude':[30, 31, 32, 33],
              'longitude':[20, 21, 22, 23]
              })
              
# haversine distance function              
def haversine_dist(x1,x2,y1,y2):
   return haversine((x1, x2) , (y1, y2), unit='mi')

# Data Processing 
df['distance'] = np.vectorize(haversine_dist)(df['latitude'],df['longitude'],df['latitude'].shift(1),df['longitude'].shift(1)) #calculate haversine distance

df['time_taken'] = df['timestamp'] - df['timestamp'].shift(1) # calculate time difference

df['speed'] = df['distance']/df['time_taken'] # cal speed

df
```

Output:

[image]